# How do I show paginated images using an array of image IDs with Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, pagination

Edited : 
I have a code , this code show `meta_post` and from `meta_post` i will show image with `wp_get_attachment_image`, every post have a `value_gallery` in 1 array and value of array is `id-attr` image , 1 `value_gallery` have 2 or more `id-attr` separated by comma , so i want make post paginate , but i dont know how make it , i was make this code on `single-gallery.php` ,

i want make this code like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/238113/) , but this code still just show "not found" , if anyone can help me , i will so very happy

note : value of meta_value `value_gallery` is array ex : `array(1) { [0]=> string(29) "1402,1435,1398,1434,1434,1434" }`

thankyou for your attention

**Edited :**
from this code i am try to show `meta_post` per page (ex: 4 per page) and trying to make pagination , updated Code :

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $ids = get_the_ID();
    $args = array('paged' => $paged ,  'post__in' => array($ids));
    $the_query = new WP_Query($args);
if (have_posts()) :
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
     $metas = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'value_gallery',false);
            foreach ($metas as $meta) {
                $key_val = explode(",", $meta);
                $image_chunk = array_chunk($key_val, 3);
                $page = get_query_var('page');
                $page = $page > 1 ? $page - 1 : 0 ;
                if (isset($key_val[$page])) {
                    foreach ($image_chunk[$page] as $image) {
                        echo "<div class='col-lg-4'>".
                        wp_get_attachment_image($image,"cherry-thumb-a") ."</div>";
                    }
                }
            }
endwhile;
 $big = 9999;
 echo paginate_links( array(
   'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
   'format' => '?paged=%#%',
   'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
   'total' => $the_query->max_num_pages
    ) );
   wp_reset_postdata();
endif;
```

**updated 2**
I will explain again with this question 
so I am trying to make a gallery post , a gallery post have a `meta_post` that value is 1 array ex : `array(1) { [0]=> string(29) "1402,1435,1398,1434,1434,1434" }` so this value is `id-attr` of image , and i will try to make a pagination for `this meta_post`

**updated 3**
this is illustration what i trying to make with this code
[image: pagination post_meta]

Comment: Since you do not get answers fast, try editing your question to clarify your problem description. Explain what are you trying to achieve? What is your code doing? etc. For guidance please read [how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: oh ya @5th thankyou for suggestion , i was edited my question

Comment: To be clear, you have a meta key `value_gallery` and that contains an array with 1 value, that value is a string with image IDs seperated by a comma, and you want to make a WP_Query to get all of the images that have their IDs in that string?

Comment: great @Alesana yeah `value_gallery` array 1 value per post , and i am try to paginate per ID on `value_gallery`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this JavaScript pagination which would be much more easier.

```
<div id="gallery_items" class="row">  <!-- gallery div -->
<?php
$gallery_value = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'value_gallery', false)[0];
$split_images = explode(",", $gallery_value); 

$imgcnt = 0;
$hideclass = '';
foreach ( $split_images as $image ) { 
    $imgcnt++;
    if($imgcnt > 4) $hideclass = ' hidden'; //hide divs greater than 4, even though pagination script handles this
    echo "<div class='col-lg-4$hideclass'>".wp_get_attachment_image($image,"cherry-thumb-a") ."</div>";
}
?>
</div>
<div id="page_navigation"></div> <!-- pagination div -->
```

Add this JS (pagination script credit goes to [Karpov Systems](https://codepen.io/karpovsystems/)).

```
/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
* Pagination Function
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * */
var Pagination = {

    code: '',

    // converting initialize data
    Extend: function(data) {
        data = data || {};
        Pagination.size = data.size || 300;
        Pagination.page = data.page || 1;
        Pagination.step = data.step || 3;
    },

    // add pages by number (from [s] to [f])
    Add: function(s, f) {
        for (var i = s; i < f; i++) {
            Pagination.code += '<a>' + i + '</a>';
        }
    },

    // add last page with separator
    Last: function() {
        Pagination.code += '<i>...</i><a>' + Pagination.size + '</a>';
    },

    // add first page with separator
    First: function() {
        Pagination.code += '<a>1</a><i>...</i>';
    },

    // change page
    Click: function() {
        Pagination.page = +this.innerHTML;
        Pagination.Start();
    },

    // previous page
    Prev: function() {
        Pagination.page--;
        if (Pagination.page < 1) {
            Pagination.page = 1;
        }
        Pagination.Start();
    },

    // next page
    Next: function() {
        Pagination.page++;
        if (Pagination.page > Pagination.size) {
            Pagination.page = Pagination.size;
        }
        Pagination.Start();
    },

    // binding pages
    Bind: function() {
        var a = Pagination.e.getElementsByTagName('a');
        for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            if (+a[i].innerHTML === Pagination.page) a[i].className = 'current';
            a[i].addEventListener('click', Pagination.Click, false);
        }
    },

    // write pagination
    Finish: function() {
        Pagination.e.innerHTML = Pagination.code;
        Pagination.code = '';
        Pagination.Bind();
    },

    // find pagination type
    Start: function() {
        goToPage(Pagination.page-1);
        if (Pagination.size < Pagination.step * 2 + 6) {
            Pagination.Add(1, Pagination.size + 1);
        }
        else if (Pagination.page < Pagination.step * 2 + 1) {
            Pagination.Add(1, Pagination.step * 2 + 4);
            Pagination.Last();
        }
        else if (Pagination.page > Pagination.size - Pagination.step * 2) {
            Pagination.First();
            Pagination.Add(Pagination.size - Pagination.step * 2 - 2, Pagination.size + 1);
        }
        else {
            Pagination.First();
            Pagination.Add(Pagination.page - Pagination.step, Pagination.page + Pagination.step + 1);
            Pagination.Last();
        }
        Pagination.Finish();
    },

    // binding buttons
    Buttons: function(e) {
        var nav = e.getElementsByTagName('a');
        nav[0].addEventListener('click', Pagination.Prev, false);
        nav[1].addEventListener('click', Pagination.Next, false);
    },

    // create skeleton
    Create: function(e) {

        var html = [
            '<a>&#9668;</a>', // previous button
            '<span></span>',  // pagination container
            '<a>&#9658;</a>'  // next button
        ];

        e.innerHTML = html.join('');
        Pagination.e = e.getElementsByTagName('span')[0];
        Pagination.Buttons(e);
    },

    // init
    Init: function(e, data) {
        Pagination.Extend(data);
        Pagination.Create(e);
        Pagination.Start();
    }
};

/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
* Other Functions
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * */

var show_per_page = 4;
function showPagination() {
    //getting the amount of elements inside content div
    var number_of_items = jQuery('#gallery_items .col-lg-4').length;
    //calculate the number of pages we are going to have
    var number_of_pages = Math.ceil(number_of_items/show_per_page);

    if(eval(number_of_pages)>1) {
        //set the value of our hidden input fields
        var pg=1;
        Pagination.Init(document.getElementById('page_navigation'), {
            size: number_of_pages, // pages size
            page: pg,  // selected page
            step: 2   // pages before and after current
        });

        //hide all the elements inside content div
        jQuery('#gallery_items .col-lg-4').css('display', 'none');

        //and show the first n (show_per_page) elements
        jQuery('#gallery_items .col-lg-4').slice(0, show_per_page).css('display', 'block');
    }
    else {
        if(eval(number_of_items)>0) {
            jQuery('#gallery_items .col-lg-4').css('display', 'block');
            jQuery('#page_navigation').html('');
        }
        else
            jQuery('#page_navigation').html('<p class="red_font">No Images.</p>');
    }
};

function goToPage(page_num) {
    //get the element number where to start the slice from
    start_from = page_num * show_per_page;

    //get the element number where to end the slice
    end_on = start_from + show_per_page;

    //hide all children elements of content div, get specific items and show them
    jQuery('#gallery_items .col-lg-4').css('display', 'none').slice(start_from, end_on).css('display', 'block');

    //remove previous active & add active to current
    jQuery('#page_navigation .page_link').removeClass('active_page');
    jQuery('.page_link[longdesc=' + page_num +']').addClass('active_page');

    //scroll to top
    jQuery('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: eval(jQuery("#gallery_items").offset().top)-50
    }, 750);
}

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    showPagination();
});
```

Hope this solves your issue.

Comment: thankyou for answer , but the nav pagination can't show :(

Comment: Are you saying that pagination not showing? Can you able to share your URL to check?

Comment: yes buddy , the nav pagination not showing , my page still on local xampp

Comment: no error in console ,[single-page.php](https://pastebin.com/Me2J38xE) [gallery.js](https://pastebin.com/1jetPAbK)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to fetch posts by an array of their ID's you will want to use `post__in` (double underscore).

Try the code below.

```
//Get the string from the meta by accessing the [0]th property in it.
$value = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'value_gallery',false)[0]; 

// Turn it into an array of IDs
$values = explode(",",$value); 

//Get the current page number from query var 'page', or if paged is not set - use 1.
$paged = max( 1, get_query_var( 'page' ) );

$args = array(
  // Use post__in to get posts by an array of IDs
  'post__in' => $values, 

  // Limit it to 4 posts per page
  'posts_per_page' => 4, 

  // Get posts from the current page we're on
  'paged' => $paged,

  // You must set 'post_status' to 'any' (or 'inherit') to get images
  'post_status' => 'any', 

  // You must set 'post_type' to 'any' (or 'attachment') to get images
  'post_type'=> 'any', 
);

// Query for the images
$res =  new WP_Query($args); 

// If there are posts...
if ( $res->have_posts() ) { 
  // For each post
  foreach ( $res->posts as $image ) { 
    // Echo the post
    echo wp_get_attachment_image( $image->ID ); 
  }

  // Echo link pagination
  echo paginate_links( array(

    // Set the base for the page links
    'base'    => str_replace( 999999999, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( 999999999 ) ) ), 

    // Get max amount of pages from the WP_Query
    'total'   => $res->max_num_pages, 

    // Use the current page number in pagination as well
    'current' => $paged, 

    // Set the format 
    'format'  => '?paged=%#%', 
  ) );
// If there are no posts
} else { 
  // Echo "not found"
  echo "not found"; 
}
```

If the post_meta `value_gallery` contains duplicate IDs, WP_Query will not be able to fetch the same post multiple times. If you need the same image to be shown more than once, you will need to create your own function to see which items from the array belong on the current page.

Here is an example of a function that would do that.

```
// Function to paginate an array of IDs
function wpse_52588027_paginated_post_ids($posts_per_page, $paged, $post_ids) {
  // If current page is higher than possible
  if ($paged > ceil(count($post_ids) / $posts_per_page)) {
    // Set current page to last possible page
    $paged = ceil(count($post_ids) / $posts_per_page);
  }

  // Find index to start returning post IDs based off current page and posts per page.
  $array_start = ($paged - 1) * $posts_per_page;

  // Find index to stop returning post IDs based off current page and posts per page.
  $array_end = ($paged) * $posts_per_page;

  // Create an empty array to fill with post IDs from the current page
  $current_posts = [];

  // For each post in between the start and end index...
  for ($i = $array_start; $i < $array_end; $i++) {
    // If the current index is higher than posts available...
    if ($i >= count($post_ids)) {
      // Break out of the for loop
      break;
    }

    // Add this post ID to the list of current post IDs
    $current_posts[] = $post_ids[$i];
  }

  // Return the list of current post IDs
  return $current_posts;
}

//Get the string from the meta by accessing the [0]th property in it.
$value = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'value_gallery',false)[0];

//Turn it into an array of IDs
$values = explode(",",$value); 

//Get the current page number from query var 'page', or if paged is not set - use 1.
$paged = max( 1, get_query_var( 'page' ) ); 

// Declare how many posts per page you would like
$posts_per_page = 4; 

// Get a list of post IDs that would be on this page.
$res = wpse_52588027_paginated_post_ids($posts_per_page, $paged, $values); 

// If there are posts
  if ( count($res) > 0 ) { 

  // For each post
    foreach ( $res as $image ) { 

  // Echo the post
      echo wp_get_attachment_image( $image );
    }

  // Echo pagination.
    echo paginate_links( array( 
      'base'         => str_replace( 999999999, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( 999999999 ) ) ), // Set the base for the page links
      'total'        => ceil(count($values) / $posts_per_page), // Get max amount of pages from the WP_Query
      'current'      => $paged, // Use the current page number in pagination as well
      'format'       => '?paged=%#%', // Set the format 
    ) );
  } else { // If there are no posts
    echo "not found"; // Echo "not found"
  }
```

Comment: thankyou for answer , but the `paginate_link` not show , and at i am trying go manually `https://mysite .net/post-title/page/2` this link will redirect back to my post

Comment: Are there more than 4 posts altogether? Try doing `print_r($values);` under where values is defined.

Comment: at `print_r($values);` this will show `Array ( [0] => 1402 [1] => 1435 [2] => 1398 [3] => 1434 [4] => 1434 [5] => 1434 )`

Comment: It looks like you only actually have 4 post IDs there. 1434 is repeated 3 times.

Comment: actually 1434 is `attachment_id` or `id-attr` so this i am use 1 same image for 3 times

Comment: You would like to show the same exact image 3 times in a row? If so - you cannot use WordPress' default `WP_Query` and pagination - you will have to write your own functions for that. `WP_Query` cannot query the same post more than once.

Comment: umm yeah , so use a custom `SQL` and use `$wpdb` right ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181520/discussion-between-alesana-and-jack).

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it you only want to display the first 4 images on a page. What I would do Is I would limit the foreach. For example this would be the php code

```
$value = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'value_gallery',false); 
$counter = 0; //initialize counter to 0
foreach ($value as $key ) {
  $values = explode(",",$key);
  $counter++;
  if($counter == 5) //check if counter is 5 one more than we want. If it is then we are going...
     break;         //...to stop the reason this works is because we haven't gotten to your other foreach loop in which it addes another image. 
  foreach ($values as $keys) {
     $args = array(
        'meta_key' => 'value_gallery',
        'meta_value' => $keys,
        'post_per_page' => 4
     );
     $res =  new WP_Query($args);
     if ($res->have_posts()) {
       $id = get_the_ID();
       echo $key;
     }else{
       echo "not found";
     }
  }
 }
```

If this isn't what you are looking for can you be more specific?

Comment: thankyou for your quick response and answer , actually i am trying to make pagination 4 image per page

Comment: @jack ok have you tried changing `echo "not found"` to `echo $res` this will help you understand what is going wrong.

Comment: yea @SharpIncTechAndProgramming i will try your code

Comment: this code still return false on `if ($res->have_posts()) ` ,

Comment: yeah it should return false because none of the main code is changed what does the echo $res output. That will give me an idea where to go?

Comment: great , now  i am use another ways , check my update

Comment: Have you tried using [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_pagination.asp) and then using jquery to get onclick for each and then display 4 and then next 4 and so on? You are getting close.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181519/discussion-between-sharpinctechandprogramming-and-jack).